# Ubuntu Budgie installation

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, partitioning, windows, ubuntu-budgie

I have just installed Ubuntu Desktop as dual boot on Windows and then after having a tour on Ubuntu site, I want to install Ubuntu Budgie. However, after reading [Installation Instructions](https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads/), I am getting confused. So, could you please clarify me about the following issues?

**1.** Should I install Budgie without installing Ubuntu Desktop? Or should I install Budgie on Ubuntu Desktop?

**2.** While installing Ubuntu Desktop, I do not use swap option as some user in here not suggest it. Is there any need to use swap option while installing Budgie?

**3.** What is the purpose of the following custom partitions? Is it just logical partitions to group data and user files in Ubuntu? And which partitions should I create?

```
/boot = 1 GB (ext4 file system)
/ = 10 GB  (ext4 file system)
/home = 22 GB (ext4 file system)
/var = 6 GB (ext4 file system)
Swap = 2 GB (ext4 file system)
```

Comment: What is best for your needs you only can decide.  With only 10GB for / (the recommended minimum is 25GB; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) you had better not want to install much, plan to *release-upgrade via re-install*) and maintain your system well, update regularly etc or you'll risk running into disk space issues regularly.  I wouldn't separate /var (you'll be better with 16GB for /)  but your end-use will dictate what's best for you (many survive on smaller /, myself I like 32GB). Which desktop is your choice (you can have both; my system has 3 installed)

Comment: @guiverc Thanks a lot for your helps, but you reply everything except from my questions. Could you pls re-read my questions and reply one by one? Regards.

Comment: You can install however you like, your end-goals will determine which is best for you.  We don't have enough detail & you're not using this site as it's intended (one question & one answer, not a question of multiple parts).  1: either works with each having pros & cons so whichever best achieves your goals. 2: depends on your RAM & intended use; I think swap is best (swap file or partition again pros & cons). 3: keep it simple & use single partition or separate /home but don't make it too small; as you've gone below minimum suggested for Ubuntu releases >17.04 (25GB is recommended minimum /)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome Diana. Your questions are more about opinions than something we can answer that is black or white.

1. The simplest way to get budgie from where you are is to just install it on top of your vanilla Ubuntu installation. As @guiverc says you can have several different desktops installed which you can choose between when you log on. Some people report the odd issue with multiple desktops but I’ve not found it to be a problem.
2. Whilst some people don’t have any swap enabled you can hit problems depending on how you use your system and how much ram you have. If memory runs short you will risk problems.
3. If you are a new user in my opinion it’s best to use the defaults suggested in the installer. As a more experienced user you might have reasons to set up all the partitions you list. If you are unaware of any reason to add extra partitions don’t do it at this stage.

Hope this helps. As I said these are just opinions and other approaches can have their merits.

Update, answering the questions in comments below:

#1 Since you say you have just installed vanilla Ubuntu the quickest way to get the Budgie desktop is to install it like any other application using the software centre or the command line. Don’t try to do that with the Budgie installer unless you want to start again from scratch. If you are not confident doing this, search on here for how to do it or ask your own specific question.

#2 The only drawback of using swap is it will use disk space. What you don’t want to happen is have the computer freeze when you are working on something important and potentially lose your work.

#3 You can run Linux with one partition or lots. I use a single partition and prefer that approach because that makes all my disk space available to every aspect of the computer. If you have a root partition and a home partition you can run out of space on one and not make use of spare space available on the other without resizing. On the other hand having a separate home partition arguably makes it easier to reinstall Linux and not lose data and settings in home.

Comment: Many thanks for detailed explanations, voted up. Regarding to your answer, could you pls clarify a little bit more about the following points?

Comment: **#1** I think I should install Budgie after installation of Ubuntu, is that true?

Comment: **#2** I have 16 GB Ram installed on my PC. But if you suggest to use swap option, please let me know. On the other hand, what is the drawbacks of using swap option?

Comment: **#3** I do not understand what do you suggest in this issue. Should I use partitions in normal conditions? And **why** I should use partition or at least home partition in Ubuntu?

Comment: Any reply please?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, been working. Hope the update above helps

Comment: Perfect explanations, thank you very much and marked as answer. On the other hand >>>

Comment: **#2** I think there is no need to use **swap** options as I have 16 GB memory. Is that true?

Comment: **#3** There is no need to create **home** or other partitions, because I will not keep my data or project files on Ubuntu partition (I use dual boot and keep all the data and project filed on Windows drives, e.g. D drive). Is that true?

Comment: #2 16GB will allow you to have several applications running at once without swap. However I don’t know what you plan to do with your system so you could could get into a position where more is needed. Swap is in effect a reserve of memory.

Comment: #3 There is no need to have a home partition but any Linux installation will create places in the filesystem for each user to store personal files. If your user name is diana that will be at /home/diana. You can choose where to store your data and that can be on a Windows partition. To do that you will have to mount the drive. For this to work you should turn off fast boot and stop using hibernation.

Comment: **#2** I develop software and of course I may need swap area. But I am confused do you suggest to use swap or not? And normally it is recommended 2 x my RAM meaning 32 GB swap area. It seems to be a little bit more. Maybe 16 GB swap area enough. Any idea?

Comment: **#3** Again, very good tricks, many thanks. In this scene I think I should create /home and /username partitions in addition to root one (/). Is that true and how much do you suggest for them (assume I need to install app that are between 80-100 GB size on Windows).

Comment: **#3-2** Do you mean Ubuntu or Windows with "_turn off fast boot and stop using hibernation_"?

Comment: #2 I would always recommend using swap but I had the impression you were reluctant to do so. You can do quite a bit with 16GB and no swap. If you have the disk space make some available for swap. In Linux it’s easy to monitor your memory and swap usage so you can see if you ever get near to the limit of what you have provided. If you do the Linux kernel will kill some of your apps though I don’t know what prioritisation methods it uses to choice which.

Comment: #3 In Linux programs are installed below / in the filesystem. You don’t get to choose where, like you do in Windows. If you are planning to install a 100 GB app that space will need to be available in the / partition. Linux always sets up a user data area to be below /home/username/ . If you set up a separate home partition that’s where the user data area will be located. A /username partition does not make sense in the Linux file system. It’s not unusual to have a mount point at /home/username/data for data held on another partition. Vanilla Ubuntu is just under 10GB so size it from there.

Comment: #3-2 I was talking about Windows. Windows will lock disks when hibernated so that the state it saved when you hibernate is unchanged when you restart. That means another OS like Linux will be unable to write to the Windows disk if Windows has been hibernated. Windows fast boot is a form of hibernation so you cannot use that either.

Comment: Many many thanks PonJar. Very useful information that I keep in mind for installation and usages.